# Solr - memory requirement for indexing

Tags: java, solr

**UPDATE: added some java code and also the command used to start the job**

I am running an indexing process as a job on an HPC server which allocates memory to jobs. I hit the memory ceiling during the indexing process, and I would like to ask for my data an usage scenario, what would be minimum memory for 1) indexing and 2) querying the index later.

Scenario:

- projected index size to be around 70GB
- projected record # to be around 150 million
- I use Java solr client, solr = 7.1.0
- During indexing I commit every 10k records
- I ran the job with 24GB allocated memory during indexing but it crashed about half way, i.e., 75million records indexed
- Query usage: very light, the index is only to be used by myself (one person) to access the data easily and query will only be sequential and mostly one field based

The Java code below is used to start a server in the 'embedded' mode:

```
    CoreContainer prodNCContainer = new CoreContainer(args[1]);
    prodNCContainer.load();
    SolrClient prodNameCatDescIndex = new EmbeddedSolrServer(prodNCContainer.getCore("prodcatdesc"));
```

The command I use to start the job is like follows:

```
#$ -l h_rt=168:00:00 -l rmem=24G -m bea -M ... 
java -Xmx23000m -cp '........ 1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar' x.y.z.ProdCatDescIndexCreator ....
```

The first line asks the server to allocate 24G memory to my job.

As I mentioned the job failed because the server killed the job when it exceeds its allocated 24GB memory. This tells me that for this indexing process that is not enough. So what is the rule of thumb to configure the memory during the indexing process? And what about later to use the index?

I remember that you do not need larger memory than the expected index size... that would be unrealistic as well IMO. In the past I manage to load and query a 43G solr index on my laptop that has only max of 16GB memory. I am confused.

Is there any configuration in the solrconfig.xml file to deal with this, e.g., configure number of segments maybe? I am not sure how to do that ...

Comment: If the server is killing the job, your memory settings are probably too high - since it's the OS killing it, and not the JVM creating an out of memory exception. In effect you're telling the JVM to use more memory than the OS allows it to; I'd try by reducing the memory made available to the JVM and let it run its GC instead.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understood what you are saying... I have updated my question adding in the command I used to start the job. Do you mean, e.g., edit the 'java -Xmx...' to a smaller value like 'java -Xmx12000m ...' so that it does not take up all the 24G allocated to my node? Thannks

Comment: Correct. If you give the JVM 24G, and the total allocated memory on your server is 24G, the JVM will eat everything and get killed when there is no more room available. On your laptop this setting is different and it doesn't get killed because it uses too much memory.

Comment: Thanks it works, if you like post this as an answer and I will tick and vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is killing the job, your memory settings are probably too high - since it's the OS killing it, and not the JVM creating an out of memory exception. In effect you're telling the JVM to use more memory than the OS allows it to; reduce the memory made available to the JVM and let it run its GC instead.

If you give the JVM 24G, and the total allocated memory on your server is 24G, the JVM will eat everything and get killed when there is no more room available. On your laptop this setting is different and it doesn't get killed because it uses too much memory.

The JVM believes it has as access to at least as much memory as you tell it, and then the OS underneath sees that "oh, that jvm process is sure using a lot of memory .. and I'm all out of available memory .. guess I'll have to kill it". When this happens, the process just disappears and won't be able to log anything (except to the syslog or depending on your operating system, a different log, which will tell you that it what got killed).